# Using typescript-plugin-styled-components with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

The docs for `typescript-plugin-styled-components` gives instructions for integrating with Typescript loaders in the webpack config. However our app is built with create react app and there's no webpack config files.

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

To modify webpack config, you'll have to eject out of CRA

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject

This is a un-reversible